# Excel: Referencing to another workbook across worksheets

Tags: excel

So I've been trying to automate one of my workbooks that summarizes monthly data from multiple other workbooks. To give some context, my workbook is a summary sheet that shows the current totals of various accounts at any given month.

As an example, my "summary" workbook pulls the account balance from another workbook called "vendor payment" which monthly tabs labelled "Nov15", for instance.

I currently use VLOOKUP on the "summary" workbook to pull the total from the "vendor payment" tab with:

```
   "=VLOOKUP("Total",'vendor payment.xlsx]Nov15'!$A$21:$H$40,4,0)"
```

I want to simplify the workbook by having the sheet reference a tab within the "vendor payment" worksheet based on a date and year I enter into an input cell within the "summary" workbook.

I currently have it setup so that if I enter in the month and year, it will populate a cell that concatenates the information into the same "Nov15" format to match the tab names in the "vendor payment" workbook. Is there a way for me to use this in a way that allows me to simply change the month to say, Dec and have it become:

```
  "=VLOOKUP("Total",'vendor payment.xlsx]Dec15'!$A$21:$H$40,4,0)"
```

I know that's a lot of text and hopefully it makes sense what I'm trying to go for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're asking.  You'll need `Indirect()`.  Let's say the cell that will return `Nov15` or `Dec15` is cell `B1` in your worksheet.  Use this formula:

`"=VLOOKUP("Total",Indirect("'vendor payment.xlsx]"&B1&"'!$A$21:$H$40,4,0)"`

Although, check the format of your worksheet reference (`vendor payment.xlsx]`), is that correct? Is that how it's named?

Edit: A quick example:

[image]

So, as I change `C1` to `Sheet2` or `Sheet4`, it'll look at the range `A1:D4` on that sheet, and return the `4th` column's relative value.  Just tweak this to match your workbooks and such.  A tip for using closed workbooks: Have the workbook open, enter the formula and use the mouse to select the ranges in your external workbook. Then the formula will have just the file name.  If you then close the workbook, it'll update itself to include the whole path.

Comment: Hey Bruce!

The indirect formula did indeed work! The only problem is that I need the "vendor payment" workbook to be open, otherwise I get the #REF error. This becomes an issue since the "summary" workbook requires the formula to pull from a large number of various workbooks. 

Do you know of any alternative methods or a workaround this issue?

Comment: @bearviking - hmm, `indirect()` requires the workbook to be open. You're saying that it's not possible/probable to have your Vendor Payment book open?